# assembly: Invalid operands error using ".equ" with a subtraction of 2 character literals

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

I am getting following assembler error when I try to assemble my code:

```
Error: invalid operands (*UND* and *UND* sections) for `-' when setting `UPPER_CONVERSION'
```

I am using following command to assemble:

```
as -32 toupper.s -o toupper.o
```

My code (I am referring the lower to upper conversion code from [this](https://download-mirror.savannah.gnu.org/releases/pgubook/ProgrammingGroundUp-1-0-booksize.pdf) book):

> ```
> .section .text
>
> ###CONSTANTS##
> #The lower boundary of our search
> .equ LOWERCASE_A, ’a’
> #The upper boundary of our search
> .equ LOWERCASE_Z, ’z’
> #Conversion between upper and lower case
> .equ UPPER_CONVERSION, ’A’ - ’a’                  ## error on this line
> ```

See the first version of this question for the full code which uses `$UPPER_CONVERSION` as an immediate.  But the above is an MCVE which produces the assembler error message, and thus isn't usable as a way to define `UPPER_CONVERSION = 65 - 97 = -32`

---

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30036738/assembly-set-directive-gives-error-invalid-operands-data-and-und-sections) question, I tried the solution, but I think it is not related (I may be wrong here).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You have some non-ASCII quote characters in your source code**:
pasting your `’A’ - ’a’` into `hd` (aka `hexdump -C`) on GNU/Linux shows this:

```
00000000  e2 80 99 41 e2 80 99 20  2d 20 e2 80 99 61 e2 80  |...A... - ...a..|
00000010  99 0a                                             |..|
```

So the problem is that your quote marks are 3-byte UTF-8 sequences, not ASCII single quotes.

Re-typing it as

```
.equ UPPER_CONVERSION, 'A' - 'a'
```

results in a file that assembles just fine.  (Containing only that one line.  I didn't try your entire file.)

Comment: Thanks @peter this is a great explanation

Comment: Such things happen if books or pdfs contain source code and some prettifier changes straight quotes into some kind of typographic quotes. I copied the same text from the pdf and got the same typographic `’` quotes. In the pdf, they actually look like `´`. I would be suspicous of all quotes in source code copied from the pdf.